# List the folders with 6 digits in the name

Tags: java, file, java-8

I am trying to list only folder which has number in names and 6 digit,

```
File[] directories = new File("F:\\war").listFiles(File::isDirectory);
for(File getDirectory : directories) { 
    Path folder = Paths.get(getDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    BasicFileAttributes attr =
        Files.readAttributes(folder, BasicFileAttributes.class);
}
```

Example :

```
C:\\war\\NewOne
C:\\war\\032678
C:\\war\\908
```

Output :

```
C:\\war\\032678
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one else condition in listFiles method using matching by regular expression:

```
File[] directories = new File("F:\\war")
                        .listFiles(file -> file.isDirectory() && 
                                           file.getName().matches("[0-9]{6}"));
```

Comment: just a note `"\\d"` also matches a digit, is an **alternative** to `"[0-9]"`  (no need to change answer, some people prefer it, IMO `"[0-9]"` is easier to understand)

Comment: Yes @ user15244370 I' see now and + from me to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` as this way:

```
String pattern = "\\d{6}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
List<File> files = Arrays.stream(new File("F:\\war").listFiles(File::isDirectory))
            .filter(file -> p.asMatchPredicate().test(file.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `".*((?<=\\\\)\\d{6})$"` to find the folder which has number in names and 6 digit:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*((?<=\\\\)\\d{6})$").matcher(getDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

About regex:

- `.*` : `.` any character, `*` zero or more times
- `(?<=\\\\)` : a positive lookbehind, to match the string comes after `\\`
- `\\d{6}` : to match 6 digit
- `$` : end of the input

Comment: 1) matches normally does not require `$` - it always tries to match the whole expression (believe the lookbehind does not change that); 2) do we really need the lookbehind? (`".*\\\\\\d{6}"` should work); 3) works only on Windows, better just check the result of `getName()` (no directory/separator)

Comment: @user15244370 think about `C:\\war\\123456\\908`

Comment: yes, what is the problem whit that? `new File("C:\\war\\123456\\908").getAbsolutePath().matches(".*\\\\\\d{6}")` and `new File("C:\\war\\123456\\908").getName().matches("\\d{6}")` return `false` - Add three digits to the end and they return `true`

Comment: check https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydvx76nr (push the Java button)   ((`matches` always *check* the whole string, not so `find` that also matches a substring))